# NOHUP Command In Linux

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, nohup

I am issuing a command

```
$nohup sqlplus "/ as sysdba" @script.sql &
```

And on executing this nohup.out file contains this error:

```
Error 45 initializing SQL*Plus
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: And what happens when you run it without `nohup`?

Comment: Its successfully getting connected

Answer (score 1):

Check the command terminators. If you have anonymous plsql blocks, typically they would look like
    DECLARE
      some stuff
    BEGIN
      sql statements;
    END;

You have to add another line with a lone "/" after it, or you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If we knew the content of your script.sql, it would be easier to assist.

But since you are saying that executing the content of script.sql does work
and you get Error 45 initializing SQL*Plus only when executing a script in nohup, I would assume you are missing a keyword `exit` at the end of your script.